Spring Batch 5 and JDK17 Job Execution Context Dao Deserialize Error
While upgrading the SpringBatch to version 5 (with JDK17) the batch job runs are failing with deserialize error from the second execution onwards. We are using a custom serializer using XStream (1.4.20) and Jettison (1.5.4). The serialized content is as follows
{"map":[{"entry":{"string":["batch.version","5.1.1"]}}]}
While deserialize we get the below error. The same content serialized from our custom-serializer is not getting deserialized back with Spring Batch 5 and JDK17 stack. The XStream and Jettison versions were same while with Spring Batch 4 and JDK11 and the same used to work there.
**
**com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct type
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot construct type
cause-exception     : java.lang.InstantiationException
cause-message       : java.util.Map$Entry
construction-type   : java.util.Map$Entry
class               : java.util.Map$Entry
required-type       : java.util.Map$Entry
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /map/map/entry
line number         : -1
class[1]            : java.util.HashMap
required-type[1]    : java.util.HashMap
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter
version             : 1.4.20
-------------------------------**

**
Can anyone please guide here on what could be the issue.
